# C# Semi-static semi-abstract variable

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, instance, abstract

It's hard to put a title on this, and if you can think of one better, I'll update it.  But what I'm looking for is a way to be able to reference a static value from an instance object.  For example, let's say you have an abstract class called `Animal` and two subclasses called `Cat` and `Dog`.  On the abstract class, I'd like to have an instance variable called `GenusSpecies`, where, of course, this wouldn't have a value at the Animal level, because its an abstract class, but every `Cat` will have the same value, but it will differ from all the Dogs.  However, I'd want to have the `Cat` and `Dog` classes to have a static value per type of instance, but I don't want to have to set it's value at each instance, but I want to be able to reference it like an instance variable since I'll be having a generic variable like.

```
Animal a = new Cat("Garfield");
```

but I expect

`a.GenusSpecies == "Felis catus"`

but I don't want to have to put 
`GenusSpecies = "Felis catus";`
 in the constructor.  But also, it would be nice to be able to also reference a `Cat.GenusSpecies` static value as it's always going to be the same per instance of the Cat type.  I know at some point I'm splitting the difference between the two ways to reference it, but is there any way to achieve both reference types?  I hope I've explained this correctly.

Comment: You may want to create a custom Attribute with genus name and mark each class with it, like 
`[GenusAttribute("Felis catus")]`

Comment: Indeed, it is a valid and really good question. I would extend this with something like execution context based OR reference based, grouped semi-static properties. For example we need to make six Team each should have five User with ID of 1...5. The ID belongs to the User but must be unique on the Team level! In this case I would use a semi static LastId OR IDsInUse on Team level but I would like to see the implementation at User for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some of the suggestions given here, I've come up with a solution, although somewhat different from what I was originally hoping for.  I was looking for the solution with the least amount of overhead when creating new subclasses and also wanted a solution that felt like wasn't a complete hack or otherwise just more verbose code than what I'm looking for.  So I landed on a solution where I created two variables similar to TheLethalCoder's solution.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public static string GENUSSPECIES;
    public abstract string GenusSpecies { get; }

    public string Name;

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public static new string GENUSSPECIES = "Felis Catus"; 

    public Cat(string name) : base(name) { }

    public override string GenusSpecies
    {
        get { return Cat.GENUSSPECIES; }
    }
}
```

At first, I was trying to access a static value from an instance variable, which I believe should be possible, however, it's just not available in this language.  So I do the next best thing and store the true value as a static value as it never will change, but I create a separate instance property which returns that static value.  It's easy to maintain when adding new subclasses, it's only just a little silly that I have to reference them differently depending the scope I'm wanting to access the value from.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GenusAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string GenusName {get; private set;}
    public GenusAttribute(string genusName)
    {
        GenusName = genusName;
    }
}

[GenusAttribute("Catus")] // or simply [Genus("Catus")], no need to type 'Attribute' in here
public class Cat : Animal
{

}
```

Comment: The OP wants it so that he can access both `Cat.GenusSpecies` and `someObjectOfTypeAnimal.GenusSpecies`. How can your code do that? I'm not very familiar with attributes (and probably the OP isn't either). Can you explain how to access `GenusSpecies` in those two ways?

Comment: The best way imo would be to implement a virtual or abstract method (depending on decision whether `Animal` base class has Genus on its own), like `virtual string GetGenus()`. Then return the attribute as described for eaxmple in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone right now so I'm not sure if this code will work but couldn't your base class have an instance property that calls the static property.

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract static string Value { get; }

    public abstract string InstanceValue { get { return Value; } }
}
```

I'll check back in a bit when I can get on my PC to test if this will work.

Answer (score -2):

you could declare `GenusSpecies` as a (readonly) string field in `Animal` and add a constructor that will set its value accordingly to the `Type` that's actually being instantiated:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public readonly string GenusSpecies;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;

        if (this is Dog)
            GenusSpecies = "Canis";
        else if (this is Cat)
            GenusSpecies = "Felis catus";
    }
}

public class Dog: Animal
{
    public Dog(string name): base(name)
    {

    }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name): base(name)
    {

    }
}
```

so that in your `Main` code you'll have:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Dog myDog = new Dog("myDog");
        Cat myCat = new Cat("myCat");
        Animal a = new Cat("Garfield");

        Console.WriteLine("Dog {0} has GenusSpecies:{1}", myDog.Name, myDog.GenusSpecies);
        Console.WriteLine("Cat {0} has GenusSpecies:{1}", myCat.Name, myCat.GenusSpecies);
        Console.WriteLine("Animal {0} has GenusSpecies:{1}", a.Name, a.GenusSpecies);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like the brave downvoter explain the the reason of his vote and have both me enhance my answer and other people learn.

Comment: You never addressed the concerns about referencing this from a static standpoint (aka. without creating an instance) and I also specifically asked for a solution to not include the assignment of this value in the constructor.